# java lock synchronization access

Tags: java, android, synchronization, locking

I encountered a multi-threaded access scenario here, so I used lock synchronization access. I want to see the frequency and severity of lock blocking. Is there any relevant detection tools or methods? My current development platform is Android, and the method of Java platform can also be referred to.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, [jmc](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html) and [jprofiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) are commonly used tools to find threading issues and other such performance bottlenecks.